# Rails 3 multitenant application design - use subdomains or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain, multi-tenant

I have a multitenant rails 3 application. I am using shared database approach (everything scope to a tenant_id).

I can think of 3 different approaches to design application controller routing:

1) Have basecamp style subdomains for each tenant
e.g., customer1.myapp.com/projects , customer2.myapp.com/projects

2) Scope each route with tenant identifier
e.g., myapp.com/customer1/projects , myapp.com/customer2/projects

3) Let routing be transparent to multitenancy. Tenant_id is obtained through currently logged in user (for.e.g before_filter in application controller), assuming the @user object has the tenant_id attribute.
e.g. myapp.com/projects

My questions are :

A) Are there any advantages or disadvantages for each of these approaches from **security, ease of development, code extensibility and end-user perspectives**? Or is it purely a matter of developer style?

B) With #1, is it possible to have a common login URL (e.g., login.myapp.com) that forwards the user to customer1.myapp.com after successful authentication? Wouldn't there be issues sharing session cookies across subdomain?

Comment: You can share cookies across subdomains.  Set the domain of the cookie to .myapp.com.  Note the . at the start.

Comment: We are in the same process of making a rails3 app multi tenant able. Do you have some answers to your questions in the meantime? Any experiences? Thank you.